# What is the time complexity of my solution that is using TreeSet?

Tags: java, time-complexity, treeset, red-black-tree

I've implemented a solution to a problem using TreeSet in Java. For every provided element from an array of size m, I add the element to the set and then read its previous and next values.

So for every element from the unsorted array of size m:

- I add the element to the tree: `t_set.add(number)`
- then I read the next and previous values of the added element from the tree:

```
prev = t_set.lower(number);
next = t_set.higher(number);
```

Where **t_set** is the tree set.

Since all 3 of those operations are log(n) - where n is the number of nodes in the tree - I think my time complexity for every input is 3*log(n).

Now if I'm correct the time complexity for the entire solution is 3* m*log(n)? I'm not sure about that since m could be a huge number but n starts at 0 and increments as more items are added.

Also if there is a more efficient structure than treeset (numbers have to sorted), please let me know.

Comment: So you add all elements to the `TreeSet` and then go over it again and check elements either side? Can you perhaps provide example code as to what you’re doing - it’s not entirely clear.

Comment: Constants are dropped, so it's just `O(mlogn)`.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: So you don’t need to previous and next from the whole unsorted array, just those added so far? Either way, it’s the same as sorting - `n*lg(n)` as you do 3 `lg(n)` operations for each of `n` elements ... and now you see why time complexity is limited in its applications.

Comment: Yes, I only check them in the tree set.